# Moq - Testing that a controller method throws an exception

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I have a controller method that throws a custom exception if a loop through a list of ids doesn't find a specified id, otherwise it returns a partial view.

I've done the test to see if it successfully returns a partial view but how do I test that the method fails and that the custom exception is thrown?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do a simple try/catch and perform Assert.Fail if you **don't** catch the expected exception.  However, most unit testing frameworks provide an automated way of testing for exceptions.

Microsoft's MSTest has the `ExpectedException` attribute which can be applied to a test method:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
[TestMethod]
public void DoSomething()
{ ... }
```

If the test method above does **NOT** throw an ArgumentNullException, MSTest will mark the test as a fail.

NUnit has a more granular `Assert.Throws` that gives you more specific control of exactly where in the test method an exception is expected.

Comment: It's always annoyed me that I can't Assert.Throws() in MS Test.  My solution to this was to write an ExtendedAssert library that takes a generic parameter for the exception type.